# Find all prime ideals and maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to solve this problem from my abstract algebra course:

> Find all prime and maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{36}=\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$.

I've seen other posts about this topic, but I still don't get it since they have orders so much lower that $36$. I think in this case the prime and the maximal ideals are the same, and I guess that's because $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ is a principal ideal domain (if this were the case, how can I also prove this? In a general case $\mathbb{Z}_n$ assuming every $\mathbb{Z_n}$ verifies that it is a principal ideal domain).

After some research I found out that the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ are $k\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,35\}$, but these are so much posibilities to check to not exist some easier way to see it, like checking only the coprimes to $36$ (or the non-coprimes, I'm not sure about what of them should I check, that's why I'm asking). How can I act in these kind of problems?

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Z_{36}$ is not a principal ideal domain, however it is a principal ideal *ring*. In general for a commutative ring $R$ with ideal $I$ the ideals of $R/I$ correspond bijectively to the ideals of $R$ containing $I$. This correspondence preserves prime/maximal/... ideals. So in this case the ideals in $\Bbb Z$ containing $36\Bbb Z$ are exactly $$\Bbb Z,2\Bbb Z,3\Bbb Z,4\Bbb Z,6\Bbb Z,9\Bbb Z,12\Bbb Z,18\Bbb Z,36\Bbb Z$$
(All divisors of $36$) By quotienting out $36\Bbb Z$ we get the corresponding ideals of $\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$. I will let you figure out which of these are maximal.

Comment: So, for example, $18\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ right?

Comment: So I know that, for example, $18\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ is not maximal since it's "contained" inside $2\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{36}$, am I right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As abelian groups $18\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$

Comment: Yes, $18\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$ is not maximal for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: So, to sum up, will my prime ideals be $2\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}/36\mathbb{Z}$? (Since they are the only prime factors of $36$). Since all maximal ideal is prime, how can I know which of my prime ideals is maximal? I guess both are maximal, but in a general case? Thanks for your support!

Comment: Yes, $2\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$ and $3/36\Bbb Z$ are the only prime/maximal ideals of $\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z$. In general the correspondence $J\leftrightarrow J/I$ between ideals in $R$ containing $I$ and ideals in $R/I$ preserves both prime and maximal ideals, so if you know the prime/maximal ideals in $R$ you also know the prime/maximal ideals in $R/I$.